# Found my iPhone 6 screen separated, how to repair it?

Tags: iphone, repair

I was traveling by air very recently, and once I got home I noticed that the button on my iPhone 6 seemed to be more deeply recessed. After a while I realized that this did not make any sense mechanically, so I removed the Rhinoshield phone protector and discovered that the screen of my phone was slightly pulled off!

How this happened I do not know, but phone is old and the battery is going downhill these days fairly quickly. It was also opened several years ago for a screen repair, so I supposed it might have somehow spontaneously popped open.

Is there any way that I can try to close this back up myself?

Could battery swelling have caused this, in which case I shouldn't try?

The poor quality photos are from my laptop. I have turned off the power of the phone right now for safety reasons.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The photo shows an iPhone 6 or 7 perhaps?  The [iPhone 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:IPhone_5_paint_(bottom).jpg) does not have the rounded sides.  Perhaps I am mistaken?

Comment: @bjbk you are right of course, it's a 6. Also I've just made some more recent edits. Thanks!

Comment: Great!  This will make getting an answer more likely.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the swollen battery could have pushed the display outwards (the battery is just beneath the display)

I would replace the battery with this guide:

https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPhone+6+Battery+Replacement/29363

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a careful read and consider if I feel that I'm up to it or if I'll seek assistance. It looks fairly straightforward, but I'm not sure I'd be able to recognize any other problems associated with the front display having spontaneously popped off (though still inside the protector) and me still walking around with it in my pocket in that condition.

Answer (score 1):

Be very careful when replacing lithium batteries as they are very flammable.

I've changed hundreds of them and still get caught out occasionally by those feisty things (due the strong adhesive)!